# I keep getting getters called on null when I try to update the user profile

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, crud, riverpod

Hello I'm new to flutter, and I'm trying to do a simple user profile screen for a user who logged in but I stumbled in some errors, the first one was for when I tried to use the **StreamBuilder()** where the stream didn't get any data from the getter in the **UserProvider()**(that's where I putted my **BL**) it kept saying **getCurrentUserData()** was called on null, so i just connected it directly to the **UserService()** and it worked, but then when I tried to edit the user info and have the **TextFormField()** be filled with the user data, via the **initState()** and have the **fullNameController** get the data from the **UserModel()** the error returned it keeps saying fullName was called on null! how do I resolve this can anyone point on where I'm going wrong about here?

P.S I'm following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQHQ1_Jen6c) to build this.

My **StreamBuilder()** connected to UserProvider:

```
return StreamBuilder<UserModel>(
      stream: userProviderData.getCurrentUserData(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {})
```

My **StreamBuilder()** directly connected to UserService:

```
Directly connected to UserService
return StreamBuilder<UserModel>(
      stream: userService.getCurrentUser(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {})
```

**UserService()** class:

```
// Get User
  Stream<UserModel> getCurrentUser() {
    return _db.collection('users').doc(_auth.currentUser.uid).snapshots().map(
          (user) => UserModel.fromJson(user.data()),
        );
  }

  // Add or Update User info
  Future<void> saveUser(UserModel user) {
    final _options = SetOptions(merge: true);
    return _db.collection('users').doc(user.userId).set(user.toMap(), _options);
  }
```

**UserProvider()** class:

```
final userProvider = ChangeNotifierProvider<UserProvider>((ref) {
  return;
});

class UserProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  final userService = UserService();

  String _userId;
  String _fullName;

  // Getters
  String get userId => _userId;
  String get fullName => _fullName;
  Stream<UserModel> get getCurrentUserData => userService.getCurrentUser();

  // Setters
  set changeFullName(String fullName) {
    _fullName = fullName;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  // Functions
  void loadUser(UserModel userModel) {
    _userId = userModel.userId;
    _fullName = userModel.fullName;
  }

  void updateUser() {
    final _currentUser = UserModel(
      userId: _userId,
      fullName: _fullName,
    );
    userService.saveUser(_currentUser);
  }
}
```

**EditProfileScreen()**:

```
class EditProfileScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const EditProfileScreen({this.userModel});
  final UserModel userModel;
  @override
  _EditProfileScreenState createState() => _EditProfileScreenState();
}

class _EditProfileScreenState extends State<EditProfileScreen> {
  final _fullNameController = TextEditingController();
  final _validator = Validator();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _fullNameController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    final userStream = context.read(userProvider);
    if (widget.userModel != null) {
      // Edit
      _fullNameController.text = widget.userModel.fullName;
      userStream.loadUser(widget.userModel);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final userData = context.read(userProvider);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          TextFormFiled(
                hintText: ‘Full name’,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
                controller: _fullNameController,
                validator: (value) => _validator.validateFullName(
                      value,
                    ),
                onChanged: (value) {
                  userData.changeFullName = value;
                  debugPrint(value);
                }
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              userData.updateUser();
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
            child: const Text(‘Save’),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you forget to return something?

```
final userProvider = ChangeNotifierProvider<UserProvider>((ref) {
  return; //return a UserProvider()
});
```

Comment: Bruhh how did I miss that? *dying inside

Comment: @ArjanitKotorri Seems like you need to upgrade to null safe dart. https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide